# PDO : Select using a prepared statement returns column name

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a prepared statement where the column is prepared

i.e.

```
SELECT ? FROM users
```

Now this normally works if I put

```
SELECT id FROM users
```

But doing the first statement, the value is the column name.

```
id = id
0 = 0
```

What am I doing wrong, or is this possible?

Comment: pdo prepare sets a value, not a fieldname so your query is simple SELECT 'id' FROM users not SELECT id FROM users

Comment: Not exactly what I was trying to do, but what I take from that I cannot do "SELECT ?"

Answer (score 6):

No you can't bind column names or table names.

Here's more info [Escaping column names in PDO statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542627/escaping-field-names-in-pdo-statements)

Comment: Thanks, not enough rep to up you :(

Answer (score 5):

A prepared statement can only replace value in the statement not field nor column name, this is because prepared statement are kind of precompiled and optimized in function of the whole statement except the value.

so this is possible:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE name=?
```

but not this:

```
SELECT ? FROM users WHERE name='john'
SELECT id FROM ? WHERE name='john'
SELECT id FROM users WHERE ?='john'
```

Comment: Thanks, not enough rep to up you :(