# pdo query select records between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This query : `payment_date BETWEEN "old date" AND "new date"` only success run if we write old date before new date. How to make it work if query `payment_date BETWEEN "new date" AND "old date"`? Because sometime the user enter new date first, then only enter old date. Example codes :

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_name, phone_number, address FROM sale 
        WHERE seller_id=? && $search_by  LIKE ? && payment_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array($userid, "%".$search_value."%", $oldPaymentDate, $newPaymentDate));
```

Comment: as an alternative, you could check the user inputs and swap them round if they're given in the wrong order.

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statements for the $search_by

Comment: How to do prepared statements for $search_by? $search_by is the field name of table in database. It is not the record.

Comment: ok.. i think i know how to do it already... just replace $search_by with ?, then move $search_by to the $result line there. Haha. Will do it now. Thanks.

Comment: @You Common Sense, I read somewhere that says we cannot use prepared statements for table field name. Reference at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583589/pdo-select-using-a-prepared-statement-returns-column-name

Comment: oh, that's field name. I didn't notice. Wel, do you sanitize it properly?

Comment: It is a drop down menu actually, not a textbox, so do i really need to sanitize it? Currently I am using `$search_by = trim($_POST['search-by']);`

Comment: Yes, you need to sanitize it, it takes two seconds to replace the values in your dropdown list with an sql attack in firebug, anyone can do that, make sure you ALWAYS validate the users input, and in this case make sure what is received on the server end is actually one of the options in the dropdown list, nothing else.

Comment: wow. Great idea. So i just need to use if else statement to check if the input is 1 of the drop down menu option, if yes then only execute pdo mysql query. Cool stuff, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always validate user input, and at the same time just compare the dates, and do a swap it they are not in the right order, like so:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($newPaymentDate);
$date2 = new DateTime($oldPaymentDate);

if($date1 < $date2) list($newPaymentDate,$oldPaymentDate)=array($oldPaymentDate,$newPaymentDate);
```

Comment: It took me 2 hours to understand ur code as i didn't learn list() yet. Finally i understood it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it just creates two DateTime objects, and these can be compared like anything else, and if the "oldPaymentDate" date is newer than the "newPaymentDate", it swaps the variables with the list/array thingy. Could be done with a third variable also, does'nt really make much different, but I usually do it this way, with the list/array, as I think thats cleaner, and with shorter variables it becomes a really neat one-liner.