# how to escape strings that are meant for database column names with double quotes?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

PHP's `pdo:quote()` escapes only single quotes, but sqlite needs backticks or double quotes for string to be interpreted as column name.

edit:
found this: [Escaping column names in PDO statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542627/escaping-field-names-in-pdo-statements)

*This is something you'd hope the data access layer would have a function for, but PDO doesn't.*

*Summary of the summary of the summary: gnnnnnnnnnnnh.*

edit2: there was a request for it but I really don't understand why they dismissed it: http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=3442

Comment: Why don't you put those backticks in when you write the query?

Comment: You don't want to do what you are doing. And `PDO::quote` is for strings  only, not for column names.

Comment: What if column name has a backtick in it ?

Comment: for sqlite it is fine that data strings and column names are escaped with double quotes in the same query, why they didn't add an option for user specified escape character, that's weird

Comment: if you are naming columns with backticks, we have another issue completely ;)

Comment: sqlite allows to name columns with backticks in it, it allows even for empty that is strlen===0 column or table names

Comment: why I must remember that not to do it , computers are made in such a way that should be possible to create layers of knowledge, so for user shouldn't bother what name she put in there, if it is allowed then why not, it shouldn't hurt

Comment: Database design is a fairly complex topic that is usually done by experts, not end users.

Comment: And since you are quoting the accepted answer of the "original question", here is an even better line from the same source: **"arbitrary column names are a problem, best avoided if you can help it"**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping field names in PDO statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542627/escaping-field-names-in-pdo-statements)

Comment: @AlienWebguy In some cases there is a need for the end user to dynamically select a particular column name. In this case we need to escape column names for to make a query safe from injection. That's why we need to escape column names.

Comment: @user393087 in MySQL you can escape a backtick by doubling it.