# PDO with k/v pairs and unknown numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I have a question about PDO for talking to databases,
the example I am familiar with is:

```
$data = array('Cathy', '9 Dark and Twisty Road', 'Cardiff');  

$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) values (?, ?, ?);  
$STH->execute($data);
```

But, if we had a k/v pair, would it be the same? ala

```
$data = array('one'=>'Cathy', 'two'=>'9 Dark and Twisty Road', 'three'=>'Cardiff');  

$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (?, ?, ?) values (?, ?, ?);  
$STH->execute($data);
```

And what if we had a none ascertainable amount of values?

```
$data = array(range(0, rand(1,99));  

$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (/* how would you put stuff here? */) values (/* how would you put stuff here? */);  
$STH->execute($data);
```

It leaves me more confused than not....

Could someone show me how the above two would work with k/v pairs and unknown counts?

Much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements only work with *literals*, not with *identifiers*.  So you need to construct the SQL statement with the identifiers filled in (and properly escaped).

Properly escaping literals is tricky, though. PDO doesn't provide a method for doing literal-escaping, and MySQL's method of escaping literals (using `` ` ``) is completely different from every other database and from the ANSI SQL standard. [See this question for more detail and for workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1543309/1002469).

If we simplify the issue of escaping the identifiers, you can use a solution like this:

```
// assuming mysql semantics
function escape_sql_identifier($ident) {
    if (preg_match('/[\x00`\\]/', $ident)) {
        throw UnexpectedValueException("SQL identifier cannot have backticks, nulls, or backslashes: {$ident}");
    }
    return '`'.$ident.'`';
}

// returns a prepared statement and the positional parameter values
function prepareinsert(PDO $pdo, $table, $assoc) {
    $params = array_values($assoc);
    $literals = array_map('escape_sql_identifier', array_keys($assoc));
    $sqltmpl = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)";
    $sql = sprintf($sqltmpl, escape_sql_identifier($table), implode(',',$literals), implode(',', array_fill(0,count($literals),'?'));
    return array($pdo->prepare($sql), $params);
}

function prefixkeys($arr) {
    $prefixed = array();
    for ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $prefixed[':'.$k] = $v;
    }
    return $prefixed;
}

// returns a prepared statement with named parameters
// this is less safe because the parameter names (keys) may be vulnerable to sql injection
// In both circumstances make sure you do not trust column names given through user input!
function prepareinsert_named(PDO $pdo, $table, $assoc) {
    $params = prefixkeys($assoc);
    $literals = array_map('escape_sql_identifier', array_keys($assoc));
    $sqltmpl = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)";
    $sql = sprintf($sqltmpl, escape_sql_identifier($table), implode(',',$literals), implode(', ', array_keys($params)));
    return array($pdo->prepare($sql), $params);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `$assoc` is for and how its used?

Comment: `$assoc` is the associative array of `'columnname'=>'columnvalue'` which you describe in your post!

Comment: Okay then I'm confusef what `$pdo` is, I thought (for some stupid reason...) that that was the arrays point of entry

Comment: `$pdo` is the `PDO` object, what you call `$DBH`. Notice the use of `$pdo->prepare()`. You may want to increase your familiarity with basic PDO usage first before you start dynamically constructing SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use ? as the binding placeholder, you can use :names and an associative array.  You can then pass the associative array as the binding list and PDO will now to match the keys of the array with the :binding_names. For example, with an associative array, if the keys match the fields in the database, you can do something like this:

```
$data = array('one'=>'Cathy', 'two'=>'9 Dark and Twisty Road', 'three'=>'Cardiff');
$fields = array_keys($data);
$field_str = '`'.implode('`,`',$fields).'`';
$bind_vals = ':'.implode(',:',$fields);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename ('.$field_str.') VALUES ('.$bind_vals.')';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($data);
```

That will handle an unknown number of name/value pairs. There is no getting around not knowing what field names to use for the insert. This example would also work with ? as the binding placeholder. So instead of names, you could just repeat the ?:

```
$bind_vals = str_repeat('?,', count($data));
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename ('.$field_str.') VALUES ('.$bind_vals.')';
```