# Insert MySql data from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<?php
$files=array(name1,name2,name3,);
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO parmi_files (name)
VALUES ('$files')"; ///// -problem is here
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

I want to insert each value from array to MySql row, please solve it out.

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO parmi_files (name)
VALUES ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')`

Comment: i know this sir, but i want it from an array......thanks for your comment

Comment: You have a syntax error at `array(name1,name2,name2,)`

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Refer to to `foreach` statement in php for iterating over arrays

Comment: @devaldcool: FYI, this is *no* syntax error, though not good practice maybe... a trailing comma can be considered *good* practice *if* you put each item on its own line, so you can rearrange them without having to pay attention to not have a comma at the end of the array, making diffs cleaner and reducing syntax errors. This is why several languages allow trailing commas in lists (e.g. PHP, Python). Writing a trailing comma where array items are all on the same line probably brings only one benefit of being consistent with the multi-line writing style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through the items in the array and add them individually:

```
foreach ($arrayWithValues as $key=>$value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO parmi_files (name) VALUES ('$value')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Not very good if you have lots of values (> 10). But then again, if you have *really* many values (> 1000), using *one* `INSERT` might not be good either. Best is to use groups of `INSERT`s with up to *n* rows each.

Comment: the last value is looping again?

Comment: Can't think of why that's happening unless the value is in the array twice. You could echo out or print the values in the array in the foreach loop and see if the same value is in there twice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to insert multiple records at once:

```
$files = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
// ...

$filesMap = implode(',', array_map(function($value) {
    return "('" . $conn->real_escape_string($value) . "')";
}, $files));


$sql = "INSERT INTO parmi_files (name) VALUES $filesMap";
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop is probably better than `array_map()` though maybe less concise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function

Answer (score 0):

### You could use a PDO abstraction layer for this

I have made a class for this in the past

It uses: PDO, bound parameters, prepared statements

and it inserts everything in one sql query and the insert looks like this:

```
$db->insertRows('test_table', $default_row, $rows);
```

### The full code

(which might seem a bit long, but makes sense if you read it) including the code for the connection would look like:

```
<?php
// Establish connection (on demand)
$db = new PdoHelper(function(){
    $db_server = 'localhost';
    $db_port= '3306';
    $db_name = 'your_database';
    $db_user = 'your_username';
    $db_pass = 'your_password';
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$db_server.';dbname='.$db_name.';port='.$db_port;
    $driver_options = array(
       PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
       PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    );               
    $dbh = new PDO( $dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $driver_options );
    return $dbh;
});

// Make a blank sample to have default values for row keys
$default_row = array(
    'a'=>null,
    'b'=>null,
    'c'=>null,
);

// The rows that we want to insert, with columns in the wrong order and nonsense
$rows = array(
    array(
        'b'=>'a2',
        'c'=>'a3',
    ),
    array(
        'c'=>'b3',
        'b'=>'b2',
        
    ),
    array(
        'b'=>'c2',
        'c'=>'c3',
        'nonsense'=>'boo',
    ),
);

// The actual insert query
// INSERT INTO `test_table` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES (null,'a2','a3'), (null,'b2','b3'), (null,'c2','c3')
$db->insertRows('test_table', $default_row, $rows); 

// The class that does it all
class PdoHelper {
    private $db, $factory;
    public function __construct($factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }
    public function connect()
    {
        $cb = $this->factory;
        $this->db = $cb();
    }
    public function release()
    {
        $this->db = null;
    }
    public function implyConnect()
    {
        if(!$this->db){
            $this->connect();
        }
    }
    public function begin()
    {
        $this->implyConnect();
        if($this->db instanceof PDO){
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
        }
    }
    public function commit()
    {
        $this->implyConnect();
        if($this->db instanceof PDO){
            $this->db->commit();
        }
    }
    public function prepare($sql, $data=null, $callback=null)
    {
        $err = null;
        $flat_data = array();
        if($data){
            $flat_data = self::flatten($data);
            $sql = preg_replace_callback('/\?/isu', function($v) use (&$data) {
                $val = array_shift($data);
                if(is_array($val)){
                    return self::arrayToPlaceholder($val);
                }
                return '?';
            }, $sql);
        }
        $this->implyConnect();
        if($this->db instanceof PDO){
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            if($stmt instanceof PDOStatement){
                $i = 1;
                foreach($flat_data as $v) {
                    if(is_int($v)){
                        // workaround for a PDO bug with LIMIT ?,?
                        $stmt->bindValue($i++, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    }else{
                        $stmt->bindValue($i++, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if($callback){
            return call_user_func_array($callback, array($stmt));
        }
        return $stmt;
    }
    public function query($sql)
    {
        $res = false;
        $args = func_get_args();
        $data = array();
        $callback = null;
        if(isset($args[2])){
            $data = $args[1];
            $callback = $args[2];
        }else
        if(isset($args[1])){
            if(is_callable($args[1])){
                $callback = $args[1];
            }else{
                $data = $args[1];
            }
        }
        $this->implyConnect();
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql, $data);
        $res = $stmt->execute();
        if($res && $callback && is_callable($callback)){
            return call_user_func_array($callback, array($stmt, $this->db));
        }
        return $stmt;
    }
    
    // Helper functions
    public function insertRows($table, $default, $rows=array(), $flag=null, $chunk_size=500)
    {
        if(empty($rows)){
            return null;
        }
        $chunks = array_chunk($rows, $chunk_size);
        foreach($chunks as $rows){
            $data = array();
            $data[] = $this->extend($default, $rows);
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542627/escaping-column-names-in-pdo-statements
            $flag = strtolower($flag);
            $flags = array(
                'ignore'=>'INSERT IGNORE INTO ',
                'replace'=>'REPLACE INTO ',
            );
            $cols = array();
            foreach($default as $k=>$v){
                $k = str_replace('`', '``', $k);
                $cols[] = '`'.$k.'`';
            }
            $sql = (isset($flags[$flag])?$flags[$flag]:'INSERT INTO ').$table.' ('.implode(',', $cols).') VALUES ?';
            if($flag==='update'){
                $cols = array();
                foreach($default as $k=>$v){
                    $k = str_replace('`', '``', $k);
                    $cols[] = '`'.$k.'`=VALUE('.$k.')';
                }
                $sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.implode(', ', $cols);
            }
            $res = $this->query($sql, $data);
            if(!$res){
                return $res;
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }
    public function insertRow($table, $default, $row, $flag=null)
    {
        $rows = array($row);
        return $this->insertRows($table, $default, $rows, $flag);
    }
    
    // Helper functions
    public static function extend($set, $rows)
    {
        foreach($rows as $k=>$v){
            $v = array_intersect_key($v, $set);
            $rows[$k] = array_replace($set, $v);
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    public static function flatten($x)
    {
        $d = array();
        if(is_array($x)){
            foreach($x as $k=>$v){
                $d = array_merge($d, self::flatten($v));
            }
        }else{
            $d[] = $x;
        }
        return $d;
    }
    public static function arrayToPlaceholder($array, $timeZone=null) {
        return implode(',', array_map(function($v) use($timeZone){
            if(is_array($v)){
                return '('.self::arrayToPlaceholder($v, $timeZone).')';
            }
            return '?';
        }, $array));
    }
    public function arrayToList($array, $timeZone=null) {
        return implode(',',array_map(function($v) use($timeZone){
            if(is_array($v)){
                return '('.self::arrayToList($v, $timeZone).')';
            }
            $this->implyConnect();
            return $this->escape($v);
        },$array));
    }
    public function escape($val, $stringifyObjects=false, $timeZone=false) {
        if(is_null($val)) return 'NULL';
        if(is_bool($val)) return ($val) ? 'true' : 'false';
        if(is_int($val)) return (string)$val;
        if(is_float($val)) return (string)$val;
        if (is_array($val)) {
            return $this->arrayToList($val, $timeZone);
        }
        if(is_callable($val)){ return null; } // TODO
        $val = preg_replace_callback('/[\0\n\r\b\t\\\'\"\x1a]/um', function($s) {
            switch($s) {
                case "\0": return "\\0";
                case "\n": return "\\n";
                case "\r": return "\\r";
                case "\b": return "\\b";
                case "\t": return "\\t";
                case "\x1a": return "\\Z";
                default: return "\\".$s;
            }
        }, $val);
        return $this->db->Quote($val);
    }
    // Debug functions
    public function getSQL($sql, $data){
        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            if(is_array($v)){
                $data[$k] = self::arrayToList($v);
            }else{
                $this->implyConnect();
                $data[$k] = $this->escape($v);
            }
        }
        $sql = preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function($match) use(&$data) 
        {
            return array_shift($data);
        }, $sql);
        return $sql;
    }
}
```